# Visual Studio, See variable's memory address in watch window

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

One particular feature I'm used to having in a watch window is a variable's memory address. IIRC Visual Studio does this for C++ (I know QtCreator/Eclipse do). Is there a simple way I can do this in Visual Studio for a C# program?

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you,

Jec

Comment: You may find [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3aw423e.aspx) useful.

Comment: Just type `&varname`, wont be much use though

Comment: The & certainly helps, I was just hoping someone made an addin for VS.

Comment: `&` will work fine, but remember pointers are *volatile* in .NET, meaning the heap can be compressed and objects moved around at any time, without warning.

Comment: I forgot about the compression, thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Put a debug point, Start your application, when that debug point is hit, Go to Debug -> Windows -> Memory
[image]

There in `Address` textbox type, the name of variable, and you will be able to see the address.

Short-cut key in Visual Studio 2012 appears as <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd>

Comment: Yea I stumbled on the address window before I asked the question. I was hoping there was an addin for VS that specifically added the variable's address to the watch window. Still (as with most things involving C# or VS) it is a work around. Thanks.

Comment: @Habib: Thanks for this answer, it helped me. A question. When I do `Debug > Windows > Memory`, the next popup shows Memory 1, Memory 2, Memory 3, and Memory 4. I choose Memory 1 and I see what I need to see, but I don't know what 2,3, and 4 are. Do you know what these are?

Comment: @AlLelopath : I believe these are for your convenience for tracking state between related memory structures.  See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28624736/1341523

Comment: I don't understand this answer, when I put in a breakpoint, the address dropdown shows the name of the method where the breakpoint resides. And instead of memory, I see 'Unable to evaluate the expression'.