# Memory 1, Memory 2, Memory 3, Memory 4 in VS2013 Memory window

Tags: memory, visual-studio-2013

Why in `VS2013` there are four Memory windows? Do they refer to RAM slots by any chance?     [Documentation does not explain why there is more than one, nor how information in them is different.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3aw423e.aspx#sectionToggle0)

> To open a Memory window
>   1. Start debugging, if you are not already in debug mode.
>   2. In the Debug menu, point to Windows. Then, point to Memory and then click memory 1, Memory 2, Memory 3, or Memory 4. (Lower-level editions of Visual Studio have only a single Memory window. If you are using one of those editions, just click Memory.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The four memory windows are for your convenience. It lets you keep track of memory content at up to four offsets. This comes in handy when you walk one data structure while building another data structure: rather than typing in a new offset every time to go back and forth, you can keep two windows open.

This is similar to the "Find in Files" window, which offers to display results in "Find Results 1" or in "Find Results 2".

Answer (score 1):

Same reason you can have Find Results 1 and Find Results 2 - you can be looking at different things in each.

In terms of debugging, the physical location of the memory is generally hidden (it may well still be on disk in virtual memory); but it can be very useful to have different windows pointed at different things. One example might be the source structure that you're transforming, and the destination structure so that you can verify it is working correctly.