# Is there a Visual Studio Code feature to easily see an object's identity (memory location) for Python?

Tags: python, visual-studio

I'd like to see the memory location (aka object identity) of Python variables and functions in Visual Studio Code. (preferably in hex code)

I'd like to be able to highlight a piece of python code in Visual Studio Code, and see it's memory location, or just type the name of the variable/function in an address field to translate it to a memory location and show the memory.

Is there a way to do this?

Looking through other answers on Stackoverflow proved unhelpful, as a previous question: "Is there a way in Visual Studio to see the actual objects in memory" was given an answer with instructions to "Just go to Debug->Windows->Memory and open one of the four available or use the shortcut Ctrl+Alt+M, 1-4."

My Visual Studio Code editor does not have a "windows" button in the "debug" menu, nor did the shortcut, "Ctrl+Alt+M" work.

It seems the available answers are outdated for the latest Visual Studio Code.

I also saw the answers from the question: "How to read the debug memory window in Visual Studio"
[How to read the debug memory window in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468194/how-to-read-the-debug-memory-window-in-visual-studio)

As well as the answers from the question: "Visual Studio, See variable's memory address in watch window":
[Visual Studio, See variable's memory address in watch window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18856487/visual-studio-see-variables-memory-address-in-watch-window)

These answers provided similar unhelpful information.

I also found instructions on "Viewing and Editing Memory and Registers in Visual Studio":
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/viewing-memory--variables--and-registers-in-visual-studio

However, the instructions in the link above clearly indicate "This feature is not available in Windows 10, version 1507 and later versions of the WDK."

After looking for "WDK version history" to try to download an earlier version that supports the "memory" feature, it appears there aren't earlier WDK versions for Windows 10, as per wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Driver_Kit#History_of_WDK

Therefore, I'd have to change my OS to be able to download an earlier version of WDK, to be able to support the feature I desire for Visual Studio Code, according to the info in the first link above.

There must be an easier way to see a Python variable/function's memory location (aka object identity) inside the Visual Studio Code editor.

If Visual Studio Code does not have this feature, would you be able to recommend any code editors that do? Thanks.

---

Here is the code that I'd like to have the memory location for:

```
def __on_message(self, message):
    # Handler for parsing WS messages.
    message = json.loads(message)
    logger.debug(json.dumps(message))

    table = message['table'] if 'table' in message else None
    action = message['action'] if 'action' in message else None
```

Comment: Are you running this in the debugger? What you are asking for doesn't make sense outside that context, in which case you can just use the `id` function in the debugger

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga As I mentioned above, my debug menu does not have a "window" button that allows me to use the above-mentioned "memory" feature. I have looked through my debugging features with no success. I'm not sure what you mean by your question. Do you mean to say there's a feature you know of in the debugger that allows you to see a Python object's identity (aka memory location)? If so, please share.

Comment: I mean in the debug console, just use `id(some_object)`

Comment: I'm not able to use the id() function in the debug console to reveal the memory location of a function that is being defined. (ex. def __on_message(self, message)). That is the reason I'd like to know a universal "built-in" way of seeing memory locations. (To clarify, I want to be able to see memory locations for every piece of Python code).

Comment: "I'm not able to use the id() function in the debug console to reveal the memory location of a function that is being defined. " Why not? `id(__on_message)`? Note, functions that are in the process of being defined don't *exist yet*. Can you please elaborate on your specific situation by adding it as an edit to your question?

Comment: Taking into account how references and memory management in general work in (C)Python: what is the problem, you are trying to solve with this?

Comment: @Klaus D. I added a code example to the question for clarification. The problem I want to solve is an error that appears when running my Python program in CMD, specifically: 2019-08-16 13:32:58,591 - ERROR - _logging - error from callback <bound method BitMEXWebsocket.__on_message of <market_maker.ws.ws_thread.BitMEXWebsocket object at 0x04221590>>: __on_message() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: @Monsieur_Renard there are a lot of fundamental misunderstanding you seem to have. "code" as in source code, doesn't have a *memory location*.  Also note, the bound-method object you are seeing an error message for is ephemeral, it only exists long enough to be called, because it's just a wrapper that provides the instance as the first argument for the  the function object you have defined on that class when it is called as a method on an instance. What do you imagine you would even do with "the memory location of this code"?

Comment: The best way to debug that is probably to see what line is throwing that error in the stack trace. Why don't you **post that**. This entire question is a good example of the X-Y problem. You really want to figure out which method is taking too many arguments.

Comment: You have demonstrated a classical [X Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). It looks like your method just needs to accept an additional argument.